# How to use bpy.context in a threading.Thread function?

Tags: python

I submit this example (What a crash blender)

I've tried everything, even context.copy (), but obviously it creates a dictionary and I don't know how to use it

```
import bpy
import threading


def threads_test(context):
    context.window_manager.popup_menu("String Test")
    

thread = threading.Thread(target=threads_test, args=(bpy.context,))
thread.name = "Test"
thread.start()
```

Is there any trick to use? I also tried to track down window_manager from bpy.data, but it also doesn't work.

Some idea?

Comment: My experience: threading will make crashes or random crashes when you access some blender data. More infomation:  
https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_gotcha.html

Comment: @XY Yes, i know this problem. I was just wondering how to get around the problem (If possible) I have spent the last 24 hours reading many pages about it and I always encounter something like "You shouldn't do this" and "Maybe it can be done" but I never have a true answer and proper

Comment: Maybe I gave birth to the idea. That is, No, you can't, or rather. You can, but only occasionally and with luck. I did some tests. So it is highly unreliable that method crash blender which is a marvel. I should create an event timers that intercepts the thread and from there to the limit launch a message. It really is that very frustrating

Comment: My solution is make a operator timer rather than the bpy.app.timer, it is more safe and easy to catch error.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that timers look like the equivalent of a modal operator. So if not managed in continuous cycles it will block the user interface. (Which is what I'm trying to avoid) I've been testing with it

Comment: The great thing about threading is that you do everything on another Core, and the UI doesn't suffer from any slowdowns due to the script (which can be very complex at times)